# Node.js: Disable UDP DNS lookup and use the given IP instead

Tags: node.js, udp, dns

I have a simple CentOS node.js server that is supposed to consume high frequency UDP messages and then forward them to another service.

Trouble is that dgram.send does a DNS lookup on EVERY call.  This DNS lookup is both slowing down the processing of the messages and occasionally getting the DNS server to blacklist the node.js host server thinking it's getting DOS'd.

The question is:  how do I send a UDP packet in node.js WITHOUT incurring a DNS lookup?

Thanks for the time.

Answer (score 1):

Glancing through the code for Node, it looks like you can pass an IP address to `dgram.send` and it won't do anything with DNS. Is it possible to look up or cache your IPs manually and then pass them to the `send` method?

Comment: Yeah, I thought so too but it doesn't appear to be happening (I'm still triggering DNS DOS protection algorithms).